# can I call my entity checkCreateAccess function from custom code?

Tags: entities

I have several custom entities in my projects.

To check access for certain links, I would like to utilize the `checkAccess()` and `checkCreateAccess()` functions in the `MyEntityAccessControlHandler` classes.

How do I call these from the Controller class or from the module file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;    

$entity_type_mgr = \Drupal::getContainer()->get('entity_type.manager');
if (!$entity_type_mgr->getAccessControlHandler($type)->createAccess($bundle)) {
  $permission = "create $bundle $type entities";
  throw new AccessDeniedHttpException("You don't have permission to " . $permission);
}
```